# <dt> <dd> styling

Tags: css, flexbox

- What I currently have:

[current photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YUyR.png)

[current codepen](https://codepen.io/ocu/pen/xxbvZoz)

- What I want to achieve:

When the text on the left is broken into two lines,

1. If there's optional second line, I want the both two lines to be aligned as in

*broken into*  firstline 
*two lines*: secondline

2. If there's no second line, I want the first line to be on the same line with the second line on the left.

*broken into*
*two lines*: firstline

I could probably achieve this with flexbox but I couldn't figure out how.

What I have tried:
HTML

```
<dl class="list">
  <dt class="imgText">    
    <span>
<img src="https://eastereggs.svensoltmann.de/wp-content/uploads/opera_logo1.gif" alt="Payback">
    </span>

    <span class="text">This text will be broken to have two lines in smaller screens:  </span></dt>

  <span class="values-container"> 

    <dd class="dd">First line [always exists]<br>
 Second line [Optional]
</dd>
</span>

</dl>
```

CSS

```
.list {

}

.imgText{
  float:  left;
  max-width: 60%;
}

.imgText img {
  max-width: 80px;
  display: block;
}

.text {
  display: inline;
}

.values-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 15%;
  text-align: right;
}

.dd{
  margin-left: 15%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: do you want the text to be aligned next to the image in order to align it with text on right??

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need??

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.imgText {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 60%;
}

.imgText img {
  max-width: 80px;
  display: block;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.values-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<dl class="list">
  <dt class="imgText">
    <span>
      <img
        src="https://eastereggs.svensoltmann.de/wp-content/uploads/opera_logo1.gif"
        alt="Payback"
      />
    </span>

    <span class="text">
      This text will be broken to have two lines in smaller screens:
    </span>
  </dt>

  <span class="values-container">
    <dd class="dd">
      First line [always exists]<br />
      Second line [Optional]
    </dd>
  </span>
</dl>
```